# "In function: undefined reference to" Static library error

Tags: c++, eclipse, static-libraries

I've included a static library in my C++ project (Eclipse IDE), but when I build the project, it generates a bunch of errors like this

```
"workspace/../ext/libxml2/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu\libxml2.a(encoding.o): In function `openIcuConverter': undefined reference to `ucnv_open_67'".
```

The tree looks like:

```
libxml2 
 |
 +- include 
 |   |
 |   +- libxml2
 |       |
 |       +- libxml (here are the headers)
 |
 +- lib
     |
     +- aarch64-linux-gnu (here is libxml2.a)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "_I've included a static library in my C++ project_" Did you link with said static library?

Comment: Copy the line(s) where it's compiling and linking into the question.

Comment: Yes, I linked it.

Comment: Is the `icu` library also being linked? Show the actual compilator / linker commands.

Comment: What I am suggesting is that when compiling, the command should end with something like: `... -lxml2 -licu`

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, I just build the project using Eclipse (I'm on Windows, not Linux)

Comment: Ok, but are you able to see the actual commands that are used to compile your program? Can you see a line with `xml2` ? Does that line have `icu` in it?

Comment: I can't find any command in the console, there are just some references to the make file, where is just a line about xml2: @$(file >linkcl.rsp,-L"C:\Data\workspace\project\proj\ext\libxml2\lib\aarch64-linux-gnu" -L"C:\Data\workspace\project\proj\ext\rcar\4.0.0\rcar_linux_HIL_aarch64_GNU\libs" -Xlinker -gc-sections -o "proj.elf" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS))python ../build/link_with_rsp_file.py linkcl.rsp aarch64-linux-gnu-g++.exe